# helm chart - range on values-files by name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart with 3 values files:

values-version1:

```
services:
  - name: service1
  - name: service2
  - name: service3
```

values-version2:

```
services:
  - name: service4 
  - name: service5
  - name: service6
```

values-version3:

```
services:
  - name: service7 
  - name: service8
  - name: service9
```

I created an iteration through these values-files through config-map template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-confmap
data:
    {{- range $service := .Values.services }}
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/{{ $service.name }}-*_platform*.log
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/{{ $service.name }}-*_infra*.log
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/{{ $service.name }}-*_other*.log
```

I am looking for a way to have:

"values-version1" services fit the 1st input

"values-version2" services fit the 2nd input

"values-version1" services fit the 3rd input

The problem is that all the files lists name are "services" and I DO NOT want to change the list name.

Is there an "if" statement that can refer to the file name?

Comment: Can you just add another variable to your values file and capture file name in there and then use that in the if statement?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you please post an answer or just elaborate your comment?

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating solution in the comment. Essentially, add another key-value pair to each of your values file, such as:

values-version1:

```
valver: version1
services:
  - name: service1
  - name: service2
  - name: service3
```

values-version2:

```
valver: version2
services:
  - name: service4 
  - name: service5
  - name: service6
```

values-version3:

```
valver: version3
services:
  - name: service7 
  - name: service8
  - name: service9
```

Finally your template becomes something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-confmap
data:
    {{- range $service := .Values.services }}
    {{- if eq $.Values.valver "version1" }}   
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/{{ $service.name }}-*_platform*.log
    {{- else if eq $.Values.valver "version2" }} 
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/{{ $service.name }}-*_infra*.log
    {{- else if eq $.Values.valver "version3" }} 
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/{{ $service.name }}-*_other*.log
    {{- end }} 
    {{- end }}
```

Note, in your specific question case I would get rid of is statement entirely and instead put what is different - like *other*, *platform*, *infra* in the new variable. However, still posting full solution as you may have other differences there in theory that are not part of the question.

Would look like this - value files:

values-version1:

```
infratype: other
services:
  - name: service1
  - name: service2
  - name: service3
```

values-version2:

```
infratype: platform
services:
  - name: service4 
  - name: service5
  - name: service6
```

values-version3:

```
infratype: infra
services:
  - name: service7 
  - name: service8
  - name: service9
```

template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-confmap
data:
    {{- range $service := .Values.services }}
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/{{ $service.name }}-*_{{ $.Values.infratype }}*.log
    {{- end }}
```

Comment: Thank you. I implemented it and when I do helm template I get version2 and version3 values inside platform as well. Did you try it locally ?

Comment: Haven't tested this exact solution, but have a similar one working correctly. Again, if the above is your exact case, I suggest making a variable that would take values platform|infra|other and use that in-line instead of using if statement.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not get it yet, sorry. Where should the variable the take values? and what do you mean by "use that in-line"? Would appreciate if you edit your answer. Thanks a lot again!!

Comment: I think because the helm does not consider the values-files name and because in all values-files the name of the list is the same, helm will consider the first services list, then overwrite it to the second services list and then the third. Maybe I should change the name of the list from inside the "if" statement or something?

Comment: Added solution without if. If that still doesn't work, pls create sample repo / gist on github showing how to reproduce your issue. Original solution should work as well, but you may be mixing values somehow.